# Constructing a good title for some question categories

Tags: discussion, titles

This seems quite difficult for me especially that I am interested for questions related to series and integration. Usually you want your question to be easily discovered by search engines but this is a difficult to task for questions that require calculations. Here are some samples

**Good titles**

[Generalized Euler sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469023/generalized-euler-sum-sum-n-1-infty-frach-nnq)

[Integrating around a dog bone contour](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2143137/integrating-around-a-dog-bone-contour)

[Real and imaginary part of Gamma function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455306/real-and-imaginary-part-of-gamma-function)

[Gauss Digamma theorem proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2075565/gauss-digamma-theorem-proof)

[Calculating alternating Euler sums of odd powers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2169507/calculating-alternating-euler-sums-of-odd-powers)

**Bad titles**

[A really interesting logarithm integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1907820/a-really-interesting-logarithm-integral)

[Integral of a rational function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2086102/integral-of-a-rational-function)

[Hypergeometric value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453147/hypergeometric-value)

[Tough quadrilogarithm integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461511/tough-quadrilogarithm-integral)

---

**Questions**

- What are your thoughts on constructing a good question for that category of questions ? (titles like tough integral, difficult integral or not easy integral seem to be too broad).
- While enforcing questions to contain LaTeX might be useful I think it is important to include some important distinctive features of the question like (integral of rational function of polynomials ) , what do you think of that ?
- Since MSE is becoming the source of most Math questions, is there any cooperation between Google and MSE to facilitate searching using LaTeX ?

**Remark**

- It seems like questions containing LaTeX in the title can be really useful especially when identifying duplicate questions and related questions. For example, once I start typing the question in LaTeX I can see some correlated questions or titles.

Comment: Some tips on good titles can be found in [How to ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959#10144) and [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/588#589)

Comment: And since you have mentioned *searching for questions that require calculations*, I will also add a link to [this collection of search-related posts](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19138/conversation/links-about-searching-for-posts-on-mse). That list was compiled before [Approach0 was created](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/24978/announcing-a-third-party-search-engine-for-math-stackexchange).

Comment: Related to the first part of your Question: [Retitling Questions: a modest proposal](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8756/retitling-questions-a-modest-proposal).  There are some known downsides to using $\LaTeX$ extensively in titles; see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex) and [there](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-latex-in-question-titles?s=6|0.7499).